# RxJava2 request optimization (android app)

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, flowable

I need an advice for RxJava2 optimization.

I'm working on a support chat for Android Application. I need to retrieve the List of ChatPOJO from the server (list of users available for chatting) and modify it with the List of DraftPOJO before showing on UI based on userId field (list of drafts, saved locally in the app's database).

Here is the request that I use to get all data from the local database and remote server:

```
             Flowable.combineLatest(
                            getLocalDataListFlowable(mDraftDao),
                            getServerDataListFlowable(mFirebaseFirestore,Chat.class),
                            (pDraftList, pChatList) -> {
                                return pChatList
                                        .stream()
                                        .peek(pChat -> {
                                            Draft draft = pDraftList
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .filter(pDraft -> pDraft.getUserId().equals(pChat.getUserId()))
                                                    .findFirst()
                                                    .orElse(null);
                                            pChat.setDraft(draft);
                                        })
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                            })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(
                            pFormattedChatList -> {
                                //
                            }, pThrowable -> {
                               //
                            });
```

Any suggestions how to optimize the code where I use Java8Stream inside combineLatest? It will be perfect to get links with suitable methods from RxJava2 with some description.
Thanks in advance.